# recording time a taxa first appears: nested loops and conditional statements in R

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops, conditional-statements

Here is my example. Here is some hypothetical data resembling my own. Environmental data describes the metadata of the community data, which is made up of taxa abundances over years in different treatments.

```
#Elements of Environmental (meta) data
  nTrt<-2
 Trt<-c("High","High","High","Low","Low","Low")
 Year<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
 EnvData<-cbind(Trt,Year)

#Elements of community data
 nTaxa<-2
 Taxa1<-c(0,0,2,50,3,4)
 Taxa2<-c(0,34,0,0,0,23)
 CommData<-cbind(Taxa1,Taxa2)

#Elements of ideal data produced
 Ideal_YearIntroduced<-array(0,dim=c(nTrt,nTaxa))
 Taxa1_i<-c(2,1)
 Taxa2_i<-c(2,3)
 IdealData<-cbind(Taxa1_i,Taxa2_i)
 rownames(IdealData)<-c("High","Low")
```

I want to know what the Year is (in EnvData) when a given taxa first appears in a particular treatment. ie The "introduction year". That is, if the taxa is there at year 1, I want it to record "1" in an array of Treatment x Taxa, but if that taxa in that treatment does not arrive until year 3 (which means it meets the condition that it is absent in year 2), I want it to record Year 3.

So I want these conditional statements to only loop within a treatment. In other words, I do not want it to record a taxa as being "introduced" if it is 0 in year 3 of one treatment and prsent in year 1 of the next. 
I've approached this by doing several for loops, but the loops are getting out of hand, with the conditional statements, and there is now an error that I can't figure out- I may be not thinking of the i and j's correctly.'

The data itself is more complicated than this...has 6 years, 1102 taxa, many treatments.

```
#Get the index number where each treatment starts
Index<-which(EnvData[,2]==1)
TaxaIntro<-array(0,dim=dim(Comm_0)) #Array to hold results
for (i in 1:length(Index)) {       #Loop through treatment (start at year 1 each time)
  for (j in 1:3) {                 #Loop through years within a treatment
    for (k in 1:ncol(CommData)) {  #Loop through Taxa
      if (CommData[Index[i],1]>0 ) {   #If Taxa is present in Year 1...want to save that it was    introduced at Year 1
        TaxaIntro[i,k]<-EnvData[Index[i],2] 
      }
      if (CommData[Index[i+j]]>0 && CommData[Index[((i+j)-j)]] ==0) {    #Or if taxa is present in a year AND absent in the previous year
        TaxaIntro[i,k]<-EnvData[Index[i+j],2]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this example, I get an error related to my second conditional statement...I may be going about this the wrong way.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am open to other (non-loop) approaches, but please explain thoroughly as I'm not so well-versed.

Current error:
     Error in if (CommData[Index[i + j]] > 0 & CommData[Index[((i + j) - j)]] ==  : 
       missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: In R, the `and` operator is not `&&`, replace it with **`&`**. This also applies to the `or` operator: it's not `||` but **`|`**

Comment: thanks I fixed this and replaced the && with &

Comment: It looks like you have a `NA` value somewhere. Use `browser()`  to debug your code and track the exact steps where the code fails

Comment: Actually `&&` and `||` are perfectly valid R logical operators and sometimes *should* be used in `if` statements.  See `?"&&"`

Comment: `&&` and `||` control the flow, while `&` and `|` operate on data (in a vectorized way). For example `&&` will not evaluate its second argument if the first evaluates to `FALSE`. When controlling flow, such as with `if()`, `&&` and `||` are more appropriate.

Comment: @RichardScriven Thanks for the feedback... I'll take note of that

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, I think you could combine your environmental and community data into a single `data.frame`.  Then you might approach your problem using functions from the package **dplyr**.

```
# Make combined dataset
dat = data.frame(EnvData, CommData)
```

Since you want to do the work separately for each `Trt`, you'll want `group_by` that variable to do everything separately by group.

Then the problem is to find the first time each one of your Taxa columns contains a value greater than 0 and record which year that is.  Because you want to do the same thing for many columns, you can use `summarise_each`.  To get the desired summary, I used the function `first` to choose the first instance of `Year` where whatever Taxa column you are working with is greater than 0.  The `.` refers to the Taxa columns.  The last thing I did in `summarise_each` is to choose which columns I wanted to do this work on.  In this case, you want to do this for all your `Taxa` columns, so I chose all columns that `starts_with` the word Taxa.

With chaining, this looks like:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
    group_by(Trt) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(first(Year[. > 0])), contains("Taxa"))
```

The result is slightly different than yours, but I think this is correct based on the data provided (Taxa1 in High first seen in year 3 not year 2).

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]

   Trt Taxa1 Taxa2
1 High     3     2
2  Low     1     3
```

The above code assumes that your dataset is already in order by `Year`.  If it isn't, you can use `arrange` to set the order before summarising.

If you aren't used to chaining, the following code is the equivalent to above.

```
groupdat = group_by(dat, Trt)
summarise_each(groupdat, funs(first(Year[. > 0])), starts_with("Taxa"))
```